# Script create duplicate convensations Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently developing a conversation system with messages.

It checks if it has an active conversation ( hasConversation function) , and then determines what it should do.

If it has a conversation, then it shall only send a message, else create a conversation and then send message.

Anyway, it seems like something is wrong with my hasConversation function.

No matter what I do, it always creates two conversations, even if one exists.

It might also act like, if I call the function three times, it might create one, 
then create another one, but then send the 3rd call message within the 2nd conversation.

What is wrong with my function?

It should check if both users are in a conversation.

function:

```
 function hasConversation(userid,user2) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            var x = [userid,user2];
            var y = [user2, userid];
            conversations.findOne( {  members: {$all: x}  }).then(function (conversation) {
         //       conversations.findOne({ members: x }).then(function (conversation) {

            return resolve(conversation);
            });
        });
    }
```

model:

```
var conversationsSchema   = new Schema({
    initiateduser : String,
    name: {type:String, default: 'no name'},
    members: { type: [String], default: []},
    time: Number,
    global: { type: Boolean, default: false},
    gang: { type: Boolean, default: false},

});
```

a conversation is created by the following:

```
function createConversation(userid,user2,message) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var conv = new convensations();
                conv.members = [userid, user2];
                conv.initiateduser = userid;
                conv.save(function (err,room) {
                if (room._id) {
                    console.log("conv created, sending message");
                    createMessage(userid, room._id, message);
                    return resolve(room._id);
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                    return resolve(err);
                }


            });
        });
    }
```

example of calls:

```
Messages_model.sendNPCmessage('59312d2b329b7535b07e273c','testing','testshit?');
Messages_model.sendNPCmessage('59312d2b329b7535b07e273c','testing','testshit2?');
Messages_model.sendNPCmessage('59312d2b329b7535b07e273c','testing','testshit2?');
```

current output:
[image]

EDIT 1:

here is the main function calling it:

```
function sendNPCmessage(userid,from,message) {
        console.log("checking npc conv");
        return hasConversation(userid,from).then(function (haveconv) {
            console.log("having conv? " + from);
            console.log(haveconv);

            if (haveconv) {
                console.log("yes?");

                return createMessage(from,haveconv._id,message).then(function (result) {
                    console.log("created mess?");

                    return result;
                });
            } else {
                console.log("no?");

                return createConversation(from,userid,message).then(function (result) {
                    console.log("created conv?");
                    return result;
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's not the code you are listing that is the problem, but rather the code that is "calling" the method. If you say you have a behavior then you need to show a ["Complete and Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will replicate that behavior for everyone. You do have problems here, so try to break them down as described in the instruction linked to. Side point: Mongoose model methods **already return promises**, so there is no need to wrap them in promises. Simply return from the methods directly

Comment: Also the english word is [**conversation**](https://www.google.com/search?q=conversation)

Comment: @NeilLunn updated.